# Adding test files to a Junit test in Netbeans 6.7.1 - getResource issues, missing file in build directory

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, netbeans6.7, getresource

I'm adding a Junit test to one of my classes using NetBeans 6.7.1, I need to be able to load a an xml file specific to testing, so I've included it in the "Test Packages" folder (along with my actual test). I'm running into 2 issues,

(1) getResource is looking in the wrong directory

(2) my xml test file doesn't get copied when I run tests (note, this functionality works with I add files to the "Sources Packages" directory).

In my test class:

> this.getClass().getResource("/")

returns:

D:\UserProfiles\myName\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjectExample\build\classes

I need it too return:

D:\UserProfiles\myName\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjectExample\build\test\classes

(As that is where the test classes are being compiled)

It seems rather hacky calling getResource, getting the parent, and then looking in test\classes. Is this the proper way of getting the path to my test file ? maybe this is a bug in netbeans ?

Also, when I right click on my testFile and "run tests" , only my test class files get copied to the test/classes directory and not my xml test file.  How do I tell Netbeans to make sure to copy a regular xml file along with class files to the build directory.

I would also like to avoid hacking the ant build to copy my test files.

Comment: Ok, issue 2 was solved by doing a Clean Build.

Comment: Although, whenever I run a new test these files get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your file in the same package as your test, say, data.xml in package foo.bar. No copying or build script hacking is necessary, just refer to the file like this:

```
getClass().getResource("data.xml");
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
getClass().getResource("/foo/bar/data.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer that I was able to have access to these files before I do a package .. i.e. I just run the tests and the java files get compiled to class files.

Comment: How do you mean that? NetBeans will just compile your classes and run your tests without creating a *.jar, and you can reference a file like this.

Comment: Just right clicking on the test file, and selecting "test file" ... only the selected file gets built and tested. I'm finding this much more efficient then rebuilding the entire project, when I just want to run one new (using TDD).

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into this problem using NetBeans 6.9.1. Here's how I solved it.

1. Open Project->Properties->Libraries
2. Select the Run Tests Tab
3. Click on Add Jar/Folder
4. Navigate to where you've stored the resource files
5. Add the folder

Now running tests using those resources will work. I tested this with NetBeans 6.9.1 and a simple Java Application.

NetBeans creates resource files in the src directory by default (default package), so I added the src folder in step 5 above. Once you do that tests looking for a resource file in the classpath will find it.

Since NetBeans packages the resources found in src folder by default, you don't need to copy the files around and keep them in sync.

If you want test resources different from production resources, you can add the test resources in the default package under the test folder. Then instead of adding the src folder in step 4/5 above, add the test folder.